# Extract Objects from list of objects based upon selected keys

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a list of friuts. e.g.

```
var Fruits={
        "Banana": {
            "Price": "50",
            "quility": "good"
        },
        "Mango": {
            "Price": "100",
            "quility": "best"
        },
        "Orange": {
            "Price": "80",
            "quility": "good"
        },
        "Apple": {
            "Price": "150",
            "quility": "best"
        }
    }
```

And, an array which contain Fruits name which I want to extract. e.g.

```
var SpecificFruits = ["Banana", "Mango"]
```

based upon above array, I want to extract fruits object and want result like below.

```
var results={
        "Banana": {
            "Price": "50",
            "quility": "good"
        },
        "Mango": {
            "Price": "100",
            "quility": "best"
            "quility": "best"
        }
    }
```

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: *"Any help/suggestion would be appreciated."* My suggestion is to make some attempts at a solution, and if you're not getting the expected result, and can't find the answer after some research, to then ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by simply doing:

```
let result = {}
SpecificFruits.forEach((fruit) => {
  if(Fruits[fruit]) {
    result[fruit] = Fruits[fruit]
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var fruits={
    "Banana": {
        "Price": "50",
        "quility": "good"
    },
    "Mango": {
        "Price": "100",
        "quility": "best"
    },
    "Orange": {
        "Price": "80",
        "quility": "good"
    },
    "Apple": {
        "Price": "150",
        "quility": "best"
    }
}

var SpecificFruits = ["Banana", "Mango"];
var result = {};

SpecificFruits.forEach( function( fruit ){
    if( fruits[ fruit ] ){
        result[ fruit ] = fruits[ fruit ];
    }
});

console.log( result );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var SpecificFruits = ["Banana", "Mango"];

var result = {};
SpecificFruits.forEach(function(fruit) {
  if( fruits[ fruit ] ){
    result[ fruit ] = fruits[fruit];
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

## ES6

you could also use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to get the required result.

**DEMO**

```js
var Fruits={"Banana": {"Price": "50","quility": "good"},"Mango": {"Price": "100","quility": "best"},"Orange": {"Price": "80","quility": "good"},"Apple": {"Price": "150","quility": "best"}},
    SpecificFruits = ["Banana", "Mango"];

let result = SpecificFruits.reduce((r,v)=>Object.assign(r,(Fruits[v]?{[v]:Fruits[v]}:{})),{});

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_.pick` method that takes object and array of keys, and returns a new object with properties from an array.

```js
var Fruits = {"Banana":{"Price":"50","quility":"good"},"Mango":{"Price":"100","quility":"best"},"Orange":{"Price":"80","quility":"good"},"Apple":{"Price":"150","quility":"best"}}

var SpecificFruits = ["Banana", "Mango"]
const result = _.pick(Fruits, SpecificFruits);
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_.pick` method by passing the initial object and the array of properties desired.

```js
var Fruits={ "Banana": { "Price": "50", "quility": "good" }, "Mango": { "Price": "100", "quility": "best" }, "Orange": { "Price": "80", "quility": "good" }, "Apple": { "Price": "150", "quility": "best" } }
    
var SpecificFruits = ["Banana", "Mango"]
var result = _.pick(Fruits ,SpecificFruits);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Another method is to use `reduce` method in order to write a clean solution without any library.

```js
var Fruits = {"Banana":{"Price":"50","quility":"good"},"Mango":{"Price":"100","quility":"best"},"Orange":{"Price":"80","quility":"good"},"Apple":{"Price":"150","quility":"best"}}
var SpecificFruits = ["Banana", "Mango"]

var result = SpecificFruits.reduce((fruits, elem) => { fruits[elem] = Fruits[elem]; return fruits; }, {});
console.log(result);
```